# MySQL select first instance from group of rows

Tags: php, mysql, count, group-by

I have a table that stores user visits like so:

```
visits (id, pageURL, date, ip)
```

Each time a user goes to a page a new row is created, so each user will have many rows all linked together through their IP.

I'm trying to come up with a query that will select only the first row each user landed on the first time they came to the site as long as the pageURL is user.html.

This is what I can't figure out, I can easily do it with PHP and a couple of MySQL queries, but It might be quicker if there is just one query doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head I'm thinking something like

```
SELECT * FROM visits WHERE pageURL='user.html' GROUP BY ip SORT BY ip, date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pageURL,date,ip 
FROM visits v1
WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM visits v2 WHERE v2.ip = v1.ip) 
  AND pageURL='user.html' -- dont know if necessary
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b669/5

Comment: The asker does not tell you that the row ID is an auto-incrementing number. How would this work if the IDs were GUIDs? Selecting the first visit of a page by date makes more sense here

Comment: If the asker does not provide enough information i have to guess. Using an unique id is normal - there for my solution is a good advice.

Comment: If you "_have to guess_" then you shouldn't really be guessing on something that *could* be wrong. Date (unless input incorrectly) *won't* be wrong, ID *could* be wrong

Comment: You are guessing like me. You presupposes that the date field only contains year, month and day. And what about page accesses near by 0 am?

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from visits group by ip having pageURL='user.html' order by id,date asc limit 1
```